# Could be possible to make Parallax effect without ToolBar on Android?

Tags: java, android, parallax

I was looking for a long time (looking on third-party libraries also) to make some kind of "Parallax" but without `Toolbar`, All I've seen is working with `Toolbar`, but it's not in my best interest, because I removed `Toolbar` on whole application.

I followed this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HO82ES_RiSQ but it didn't convince me...

There's anybody who can resolve this issue? I would like to know how can I do Parallax without using `Toolbar`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in just three steps :)

1. Add `compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'` to your dependencies in *build.gradle* ([project on github](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView))
2. Create layout with ImageView, scrollable content and **ObservableScrollView** as container.

   **activity_layout.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView      
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/observable_scrollview"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/image_view"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:adjustViewBounds="true"
              android:src="@drawable/example" />
          <View
              android:id="@+id/your_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="600dp"
              android:background="@android:color/black" />
      </LinearLayout>
   </com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView>
   ```
3. Set **ObservableScrollViewCallbacks** in your ObservableScrollView and translate over y axis your ImageView in onScrollChange method

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  ObservableScrollViewCallbacks {
       private ImageView imageView;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
            ObservableScrollView observableScrollView = (ObservableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.observable_scrollview);
            observableScrollView.setScrollViewCallbacks(this);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
       }

       @Override
       public void onScrollChanged(int scrollY, boolean firstScroll, boolean dragging) {
            imageView.setTranslationY(scrollY / 2);
       } 
   }
   ```

Very important is **imageView.setTranslationY(scrollY / 2);** which means that your ImageView is scrolling two times slower than your scrolling content.

And here is how it looks like:

[image: Parallax image]

Comment: I had seen recently this code and It seems to be in my best interest (but I didn't see this example, all examples are using toolbar at main page) thanks you very much!

Comment: Hey friend! I'm getting some problems adding a new layout (I don't want to have Parallax effect this new one) instead of this black-view, can you help me please?

Comment: Hey please can you reply to me with an answer? thanks you very much!

Comment: What problem do you have? You can replace view with id   android:id="@+id/your_content" with your layout.

Comment: Why is the library needed for this? You could do scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener on a normal scrollview

Comment: Nevermind, it seems that there are some flickering issues when not using the library

Comment: You can try to use NestedScrollView from support library instead ScrollView and it should also works

Comment: @lukjar I found this solution but every ImageView and TextView that I had, when I got them inside the ObservableScrollView they got in random positions and I can't change their positions. Can you help me?